# Ruby doublets comparing with index

Tags: ruby, arrays, compare

Anyone who can help me make this work?

```
array.each_with_index do |buffer,index|

    if array[index][8] == array[1..7][8]
      puts "match found"
    end
end
```

I want to compare if there is any doublets, but how do i define the search range to be my array index value from 1 to 7 except the index?

just to make it clear i want to compare `array[1][8],[2][8],[3][8]` and so on except `[index][8]`

Thanks 4 ur help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `group_by` to create groups of any doublets:

```
array.group_by {|v| v[8] }
```

This'll give you a hash of `{"group key" => ["group", "members"]}`.

To get a list of all doublets, just select the groups that have more than one member:

```
array.group_by {|v| v[8] }.values.select {|g| g.length > 1 }
```

Furthermore, to eliminate any doublets from the list:

```
array.group_by {|v| v[8] }.values.map(&:first)
```

This will return a new array with any doublets eliminated, so that only the first item in any given doublet is returned.

```
array = [
  %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9),
  %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9),
  %w(a b d e f g h i j),
  %w(a b d e f g h i j),
  %w(j k l m n o p q r)
]

pp array.group_by {|v| v[8] }.values.map(&:first)

# Output:
# [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
# ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
# ["j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ar =  [1,2,8,4,5,6,7,8]
last = ar.last
puts "match found" if ar[0..-2].any?{|el| el == last} # => match found
```

The hard part perhaps is the `ar[0..-2]` bit.`ar[1..-1]` would have resulted in the array sliced from the second element to the end; `ar[0..-2]` takes everything from the beginning to the end minus one. Note this quits after one match is found. The following code counts the matches:

```
ar =  [1,2,8,4,5,6,7,8]
puts "found #{ar[0..-2].count(ar.last)} matches."
```

Comment: do you have any tip to make it check if there is more doublets, because in my solution i must make sure to find all, and there can be further doublets? but thanks, it still helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count the doublets?

```
array[0..-2].find_all{|el| el == array.last}.length
```

Or do you want the index value of each doublet?

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

array[0..-2].each_with_index do |el, idx|
  hash[el] << idx if el == array.last
end
```

Comment: the main point with finding doublets is that if there is doublets then i have to resort the array. i know how to sort it but finding doublets is a bit hard. I was thinking about something like: if any doublets then XXXX

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays, no? And you want to check if there are doubles of the index'th array's 8th value?

```
array.map{|a| a[8]}.count(array[index][8]) > 1
```

To just check if the last element is repeated in an array, do this:

```
array[0...-1].include? array.last
```

Comment: exactly what i am looking for, but i get this error, with the array map code: program.rb:69:in `[]': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
from program.rb:69:in `block in <main>'
from program.rb:33:in `each'
from program.rb:33:in `each_with_index'
from program.rb:33:in `<main>'

Comment: group_by looks better to be honest. Check below. And no idea why you'd get an error without seeing code. Good luck!